# Getting scala type/package suggestions in IDEA to work

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm attempting to get type help in scala/sbt using IntelliJ.  I'm getting syntax highlighting in the IDE, but no type help or autocompletion except for built-in types, and I'm wondering what I've done wrong here (new user).

From the screenshot, IDEA knows it's scala and that the spark libraries are there.  From the console, the project compiles/runs cleanly.  But IDEA seems to ignore the existence of packages/types related to spark.

Symptom is that hovering existing types yields nothing, and `import org.` fails to result in relevant suggestions.

What I've tried:

- Verified project libraries has a scala SDK (2.11.8)
- Verified that IDEA has the scala plugin installed
- In the SBT window, ran force refresh of build.sbt (recommended elsewhere)
- Several times ran File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart  (recommended elsewhere)
- Recreated sample project new in IDEA (rather than importing existing)

[image]

Comment: For some reason the source root is not configured correctly, `src/main/scala` directory should be displayed in blue, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-content-roots.html. If the issue persists, file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL with the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085).

Answer (score 1):

There were two problems:  as @CrazyCoder posted, one issue was that src/main/scala wasn't flagged as a source folder.  But the reason that was the case was that in Project Settings -> Modules, there was a duplicate module definition with a funky configuration.

At first, flagging the right folder as source wasn't possible due to the module definition.  With only a root module present, the rest of the configuration went according to the documentation cited and worked.